# form submit event not being received

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a reusable form component (user create & user edit with same form component)

My form component is called `user-form.component.ts` and a parent component is called `new-user.component.ts`.

I know it's going to be some small fix, but everything seems to be hooked up correctly (from what I've learned, just starting) and I've been staring at it for way too long. I have another example that works, but can't seem to find what's different.

In my console.log in `user-form`, the `onSubmit` event happens, but the emitted event isn't being picked up by the parent component, `new-user`.

One last thing, I am not seeing any errors.

```
// new-user.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'new-user',
  templateUrl: 'app/users/templates/new-user.template.html',
  directives: [UserFormComponent],
})
export class NewUserComponent{
  newUserForm:  ControlGroup;

  userFormEmit(form){
    // receive the user form from a child form component
    // TODO: this isn't being seen from child form component

    console.log('received submitted form', form);
    this.newUserForm = form;
  }
}


// new-user.template.html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Create New User</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 well">
      <tut-user-form></tut-user-form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


// user-form.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'tut-user-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/users/templates/user-form.template.html',
  outputs: ['userFormEmit']
})
export class UserFormComponent{
  userForm: ControlGroup;

  //outputs
  userFormEmit = new EventEmitter()

  onSubmit(){
    // submit the form and emit an event to parent component
    console.log("emitting form submit...");
    this.userFormEmit.emit({form: this.userForm});
  }

  constructor(fb:   FormBuilder){
      this.userForm =   fb.group({
            name:   ['',    Validators.required],
            email:  ['', Validators.required],
            phone: ['', Validators.required],
      street: [],
      suite: [],
      city: [],
      zipcode: [],
        });
  }
}


// user-form.template.html
<form [ngFormModel]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  ...fields

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a binding to the event missing

```
<tut-user-form (userFormEmit)="userFormEmit($event)"></tut-user-form>
```